# Running a function using Crown WordPress on one day a week, for example, Mondays of every week

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wp-cron, scheduled-posts

**Hello friends**

I am trying to write a plugin to be able to publish a post on a *specific day*.
 I need to be able to publish a specific text as a post on **Mondays every week**.
The searches I did on the Internet
I found a code (thanks to its author) that can publish a post at certain times in seconds.
It means one minute 60 seconds and one hour 3600 seconds
Can you help me determine the day?
**For example, execute the function on Monday at 13:00** , publish a post
Thank you for your guidance

```
function bf_add_custom_schedule( $schedules )
{
    $schedules[ 'every_thirty_seconds' ] = array(
        'interval' => 30,
        'display'  => 'Every 30 seconds',
    );
    return $schedules;
}
function bf_schedule_custom_event()
{
    add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'bf_add_custom_schedule' );

    if( !wp_next_scheduled( 'bf_your_custom_event' ) )
    {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_thirty_seconds', 'bf_your_custom_event' );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'bf_schedule_custom_event' );

// fire custom event

function bf_do_something_on_schedule()
{
    $args = [
        'post_title' => 'Post by wp cron every 3 seconds',
        'post_content' => 'text',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
     ];

     wp_insert_post($args);    
}

add_action( 'bf_your_custom_event', 'bf_do_something_on_schedule' );
```

Comment: Any specific reason you want to do it programmatically? WordPress comes with a built-in option to schedule posts. Also, WP Cron isn't suitable for this type of scheduling. Why don't you use Server's cron instead?

Comment: Thank you for your comment - yes - it is necessary to do it separately from the schedule of posts in WordPress - maybe because just as I do not have much knowledge about WordPress programming, I do not have much knowledge about server and cron either. @abhik